# Why can't I put JS code between <script src="...">CODE</script>?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the following but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
<script src="/script.js">
 alert(hello);
</script>
```

Script.js simply contains `var hello = "world"`.

Can you not put code between `<script src="...">CODE RIGHT HERE</script>`?

If I skip `src` it works:

```
<script src="/script.js">    </script>
<script>
 alert(hello);
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: @foxygen Trott answered it below I believe. I didn't answer. I can answer only in 2 days my own question by StackOverflow rules.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question at any time; you just can't accept it for 2 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the `src` attribute or include the code as the content of the `script` tag. As you've discovered, you can not do both simultaneously.

Here's what [Mozilla Developer Network has to say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) about the `src` attribute (emphasis at the end added):

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document. **script elements with an src attribute specified should not have a script embedded within its tags.**

You can also come to the same conclusion by carefully reading the W3C Recommendation at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html but I don't see it stated so concisely. (Correction welcome! Maybe I'm just not seeing it.) You have to follow along the steps to preparing a script.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it can be done but only if the script you're referencing with the src attribute evaluates the contents using something like:

```
eval(document.currentScript.textContent);
```

However I would advise against doing this as it violates standards.